# Ubuntu 17.10 login freeze

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, ubuntu-16.04, gnome

Yesterday I tried to upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10.
When I upgraded to 17.04 it went all good, no problem.

But when I installed 17.10 I deleted the obsolete packages when it asked me to, and it changed my standard gnome loader to some new one.
And now when I am at the window to select the user, I can't move my mouse or input anything from my keyboard, just my poweroff works.

I tried to unplug the adapter and plug it in to see if it just freezes, but it does not, it recognizes when I plug/unplug the charger, everything seems fine, but the keyboard and mouse.

I tried to run a different kernel, or run in recovery mode but when I boot it freezes in the process.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using a laptop because you mentioned charger.

There might be an option in the BIOS for `Legacy USB support` try enabling that.

I only suggested that because I had the same problem and when I removed all of the packages, my keyboard and mouse drivers got removed as well, so I had to switch that option so it worked. After you boot and login, you can download drivers again and than you can disable this option.

Alternatively you can try plugging in external USB keyboard and trying if it works.

P.S.: When I booted my PC to linux for the first time, none of my USB peripherals worked, so I had to use PS2 keyboard and mouse to navigate, but when I enabled that option in BIOS, I was able to use it normally.

Can you explain in more detail, how it "freezes" when you boot into recovery(I expect you calling CLI recovery)

EDIT:
you can try following these steps:

```
use alt+f2 and login into a separate terminal session

remove gnome with
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session

update broken packages
sudo apt-get -f install
run it twice!

reinstall it
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session

reboot
```

Comment: I enabled it, i tried 2 wired mouses and it does not work

Comment: I am refering to the cli boot, yes, I loaded 4.10.0-38 in recovery mode, and I tried the option to repair the broken packages and then resume it

Comment: Can you try plugging in an external USB keyboard? Check if that one works

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/pdPfVdS.jpg this is where it just stops, i will try now a keyboard, see if it works

Comment: I edited my answer above

Comment: That worked, my mouse and keyboard work good now, but now i got the infinite login loop

Comment: I changed to gnome classic from gnome xorg and it worked